# Sorting DataGridView based on cell Tags

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, datagridview, tags

I have implemented sorting based on integer cell Tags this way using the SortCompare() event:

```
private void dataGridView1_SortCompare(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.HeaderText == "From")
    {
        e.SortResult = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex1].Cells[e.Column.Index].Tag).CompareTo(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex2].Cells[e.Column.Index].Tag));
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

I wonder if there is a more efficient/compact/better way to do that?

Comment: If so, what's the purpose of `SortCompare`? I don't think there is another approach, it's a pity that `DataGridView` doesn't have some property like `DataGridViewRowSorter` like `ListViewItemSorter` in `ListView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there isn't.
Just simplifying how cells are referenced:

```
e.SortResult = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[e.Column.Index,e.RowIndex1].Tag).CompareTo(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[e.Column.Index,e.RowIndex2].Tag));
```